# Define probability measure on the space of multivalued function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis, measure-theory, multivalued-functions

Suppose I have a collection of `multivalued functions` $f:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{3+}}$. It is also known that this space is a vector space.

We define distance between two multivalued function $f^{(1)}$ and $f^{(2)}$ as:  $\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{i=1}^3|f^{(1)} _i(\theta)-f^{(2)} _i(\theta)|d\theta$.

Now, my question is: how to define probability measure on this space of `multivalued function`? Any idea is this regards is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to provide more details, otherwise there's plenty of ways to define *any* measure, for instance - a measure concentrated in one point. In particular, how the distance is defined?

Comment: @Jorkug. I added some more details now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Looking at this metric I think you didn't actually mean [multivalued](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function), but rather just a normal map to a three-dimensional space. You also didn't specify the $\sigma$-algebra (Borel?), what kind of functions are considered ($L_1$?), and what kind of measure do you need (my example in the previous comment still works). It may be a good idea to read a textbook on stochastic processes, since the question seem to refer to this field.

Comment: It's a matter of terminology, without further details it can cause misunderstandings. The same goes for other issues, as it is now I do not undertand what is being asked.